# Upgrading out of support Microsoft SQL instance multiple questions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, windows-server

I just got a new job as an analyst but I’m being tasked with an administrator task and just looking for insight.

We have a Windows server 2003 (32bit) that has Microsoft SQL Server 2005. I have been tasked with upgrading it to the latest possible windows & SQL server.

Since both the sql server and host OS have been unsupported for years now I figured it might be easier to create a new server and restore a backup of the databases on the new server.
My questions are:

1. What would be the latest OS and SQL server versions that would restore a 32 bit sql server backup? (New OS and SQL server will be 64 bit)
2. If the OS and SQL server are both 64 bit, would I still be limited to 4gb ram when interacting with the database? Or is the version of a the OS what dictates ram?
3. Can I backup the entire instance (preferably with local user information) or do I backup each database individually?
4. If you have had a similar experience, what is the #1 thing you suggest I look out for?

Relevant information

- Both the old and new servers are VM’s that I create through VMware
- Licensing is not a factor so if I need multiple steps that is ok
- the sql server is interacted with by a couple dozen users who use windows 10&11 and Ubuntu 16, 18, 20, & 22

Answer (score 5):

1. The bitness of the backup does not affect anything. What does affect things is the version of the backup. Backups *before* 2005 cannot be restored without an intermediate step, but 2005 is fine to upgrade even to 2022.
2. As I said, the bitness of the database is irrelevant. New versions of SQL Server can use as much RAM as you have.
3. Each database needs a separate backup. Do not backup `master`, `tempdb` or `msdb`, just do a manual migration of logins, permissions, Agent jobs etc.
4. Is opinion-based and out of scope for this site.

Further considerations:

- The minimum compatibility level for new versions of SQL Server is 100. I would advise you to upgrade to the latest one (160), and review all breaking changes to ensure you are not affected.
- Other new Database Scoped Configuration should ideally be set. Check the `model` database on the new installation for default settings.
- Make sure the `PAGE_VERIFY` setting is `CHECKSUM`.
- Run `CHECKDB` when done.